# Adding sources to sources.list still gives me E: Unable to locate package banner

Tags: kali-linux

I have  Linux kali 3.12-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.12.6-2kali1 (2014-01-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux. I logged in as root, and tried to download using sudo apt-get install banner and I got

```
E: Unable to locate package banner
```

I searched around and then I added the following to my `sources.list`

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

I still get `E: Unable to locate package banner`

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `apt-get update` first? If you did not, then run it, and try again.

If you can't still find the package, do `apt-cache search banner` to show a list of packages beginning with `banner`.

If you can't still find the package, it means it's no longer available.

Comment: 1. `apt-cache pkgnames` doesn't require sudo.  2. `apt-cache pkgnames` only searches amongst *installed* packages.  3. use `apt-cache search -n banner` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Debian does not provide a package named `"banner"`.  They do provide [`sysbanner`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/sysvbanner), which may be what you are looking for:

> Displays a `banner' text the same way as the System V banner does:
>   horizontally.

I found that using [`aptitude`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude).  As suggested in a comment to the other answer, you could also see this (in Debian/testing) using [`apt-cache`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cache):

```
$ apt-cache search banner
adzapper - proxy advertisement zapper add-on
bsdmainutils - collection of more utilities from FreeBSD
claws-mail-multi-notifier - Various new mail notifiers for Claws Mail
doscan - port scanner for discovering services on large networks
figlet - Make large character ASCII banners out of ordinary text
libapache2-mod-layout - Apache web page content wrapper
linuxlogo - Color ANSI System Logo
nast - packet sniffer and lan analyzer
privoxy - Privacy enhancing HTTP Proxy
sysvbanner - System-V banner clone
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages
wesnoth-1.10-sof - "The Sceptre of Fire" official campaign for Wesnoth (branch 1.10)
```

which shows another package providing a `banner` program: [bsdmainutils](https://packages.debian.org/sid/bsdmainutils).  The others are probably not of interest to OP.

The suggested command, as such, would show only this:

```
$ apt-cache search -n banner
sysvbanner - System-V banner clone
```